# How find orientation of certain pixels of branches?

Tags: matlab, orientation

With this code (created for the question) I show you an example of my problem where `I` is a matrix pair of 0 and 1. You say that the image that one gets represents two "branches" of a skeleton. As you can see certain pixel of the two branches seems to be in the same orientation. What I want to do is take three by three the pixels of each branch and compare their orientation (angle) and if we get the same orientation for the two branches then fill the space that separates the pixels with 1

```
I=zeros(20,20);
I(1,15)=1; I(2,14)=1; I(3,13)=1; I(1,16)=1;

I(4,12)=1;
I(7,9)=1;
I(8,8)=1;
I(9,7)=1;
I(9,6)=1;
I(9,5)=1;
I(10,4)=1;

CC=bwconncomp(I); 
I=labelmatrix(CC); %Labeling of branches

imagesc(I) % figure of problem
I(5,11)=1;
I(6,10)=1;

figure, imagesc(I) % figure of solution that I search
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compared the 1st degree polynomial coefficients of each branch edges:

```
% generate branches image
I=zeros(20,20);
I(1,15)=1; I(2,14)=1; I(3,13)=1; I(1,16)=1;
I(4,12)=1;
I(7,9)=1;
I(8,8)=1;
I(9,7)=1;
I(9,6)=1;
I(9,5)=1;
I(10,4)=1;
% find connected components
CC=bwconncomp(I);
% get xy coords of connected components
[Y,X] = cellfun(@(ind) ind2sub(size(I),ind),CC.PixelIdxList,'UniformOutput',0);
% get 1st degree polynomial coeffs for each component edges
p1 = cellfun(@(x,y) polyfit(x(1:2),y(1:2),1),X,Y,'UniformOutput',0);
p2 = cellfun(@(x,y) polyfit(x(end-1:end),y(end-1:end),1),X,Y,'UniformOutput',0);
% compare polynomial coefficients
D = pdist2(cell2mat(p1'),cell2mat(p2'));
% find "close" coefficient values
D = D + eye(size(D));
EPS = 1e-3;
[idx1,idx2] = find(D < EPS);
A = zeros(size(I));
[xg,yg] = meshgrid(1:20);
for ii = 1:numel(idx1)
    % chosen poly coeffs
    p = p1{idx1(ii)};
    % relevant xy values
    yy = polyval(p,xg);
    xx = [X{idx1(ii)}(1)+1:X{idx2(ii)}(end)-1 X{idx2(ii)}(end)+1:X{idx1(ii)}(1)-1];
    % fill missing pixels
    A = A + (CC.NumObjects + 1 + ii)*((abs(yy - yg) < EPS) & ismember(xg,xx));
end
subplot(121);
I = labelmatrix(CC); %Labeling of branches
imagesc(I) % figure of problem
subplot(122);
I2 = double(I) + A;
imagesc(I2) % figure of solution that I search
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you say me what is EPS please?

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing but taking into account only certain pixels of the branches? For some of my branches the coefficient will be different because we take into account the whole branch but if we take only two or three pixels at the end of branch then the coefficient could be equal in the comparison.

Comment: EPS is just a small number helps to find "very close" coefficients. Currently it is done *only for the two pixels in each branch edge*, so this is what you're asking for.

Comment: When I run your solution on the whole of my skeleton (so several pixels missing to fill) it only shows me the last found and I do not understand why :-0

Comment: small bug in `A = A + (CC.NumObjects + 1 + ii)*((abs(yy - yg) < EPS) & ismember(xg,xx));`. edited my answer.

Comment: If I search the degree of branch 1 (560:561,33:34) and branch 2 (563:564,29:30), How can I do?
Iwant to compare by eyes the degree of the two pixels in 2 branch edge